# Unable to retain values in form after unsuccessful submission of form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a form in codeigniter where user needs to fill data and submit it, but after submission of form if there are any errors the user gets redirected back to the form, however at this stage the values that he had entered should stay in the form.

I am getting the flashdata error but the values are not getting retained in the form. I tried to use set_value but just getting blank form in return. Can any one please point out the error

View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('student/data/'.$student->id); ?>
  <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('req_msg'); ?></p>
    <?php
    $data = array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => 'Full Name',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'form-first-name',
        'value' => set_value('name')
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_input($data); ?>  

    <?php
    $data = array(
        'type'=>'tel',
        'pattern'=>'^\d{10}$',
        'name' => 'contactno',
        'placeholder' => 'Enter 10 digit Contact No',
        'class' => ' form-control',
        'required' => 'required',
        'id' => 'form-first-name',
        'value' => set_value('contactno')
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_input($data); ?> 

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php
      $data = array(
          'type' => 'submit',
          'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
          'name' => 'submit',
          'content' => 'Upload',
          'id' => 'btn-submit'
      );
      echo form_button($data);
      ?>
    </div>                                

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contactno', 'Contact Number', 'trim|is_unique[student.contactno]');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
  {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('req_msg', 'Contact number already exists');
    redirect('student/data/'.$studentid);
  }
```

Comment: when it redirects it will unset/reset all data. You have to use AJAX instead of this

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam can you please tell how can i use ajax

Comment: http://michaelsoriano.com/how-to-ajax-validate-forms/

Comment: I have another solution. Need to know your controller's method code. Provided script is a part of that method only. Need to know complete code of that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view file's code is absolutely correct. You only need to few modifications in your controller's method.

There few key points you need to know before implementing solution in your code:

1. Redirect only when your validation rules passes successfully and your motive behind taking user's input is done
2. When your validation rules does not pass then load your view instead redirecting it
3. Put form_error(FIELD_NAME) along with each input to show validation error

Below is the example of action:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contactno', 'Contact Number', 'trim|is_unique[student.contactno]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
        // Your database or model function calling will be coded here and make sure it returns boolean value
        if ($isTrue) {
 $this->session->set_flashdata('req_msg', 'Congrats! You have successfully submitted data');
 redirect('student/data/'.$studentid);
        }else{

           // Handle error logs here
         }
    }
    $this->load->view('your_view', $this->view_data);
}
```

This is the complete solution. I am sure you will get all the values set in form field in case of validation rule fails.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you redirect after FALSE form_validation. You must load the view there like below :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    //your code
    $this->load->view('your_view', $this->view_data);
}
```

In your view you have to use **set_value()** in your inputs.

More info @ [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)